# Install Hue in Amazon EMR

Tags: hue

I tried installing Hue in Amazon EMR using the link https://github.com/cloudera/hue .I am seeing the status

> `development server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Am also able to curl the url and but getting blank page. The curl content.

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/beeswax">
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>"
```

But when I hit the browser using the public dns url with port 8000 i am getting error page. Am i missing any steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What error page are you seeing? It could be just that you did no open 8000 or binded the server on runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 when started it. Also it is recommended to start Hue with runcpserver instead of the development server.

Answer (score 0):

You are running on the loopback interface 127.0.0.1.  This is only accessible from the host not externally.  You need to change you hue.ini
and set:

http_host=0.0.0.0